# How to create an alias that launches zathura with tabbed

Tags: bash, zsh, alias, zathura

So tabbed outputs it's `xid` when you run it. How could I put this into an alias dynamically?

I'm looking to do something like:

```
alias zathura = tabbed -c zathura -e ${tabbed Xid goes here} & disown
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [command substitution](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Command-Substitution) in your alias:

```bsh
alias zathura='zathura -e $( tabbed -c ) & disown'
```

Note that the alias's replacement text needs to be `'`quoted in single quotes`'` to prevent `tabbed -c` from being expanded immediately when the alias is defined.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can make use of `tabbed`'s `-r` command:

```bsh
alias zathura='tabbed -c -r 2 zathura -e id'
```

Relevant documentation from the man page for `tabbed`:

```
-r narg
               will replace the narg th argument in command with the window id, rather than appending it to the end.
```